# Как загрузить апплет на клиентский компьютер и стартовать его из веб-приложения, написанного на nodeJs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, веб-программирование, applet

Серверное приложение было написано раньше на java и на клиентском компе выполнялся java Applet. Теперь переписали на приложение на nodeJs. На странице имеется кнопка, по которой должен стартовать applet и выполнить свою функцию. Как его вызвать из nodeJs кода?

```
public class MyAppletNew extends Applet {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Hello Applet", 200, 50);
    }

}
```

Вот html:

```
<body>
  <h1> Hi html works </h1> 
  <applet code="MyAppletNew.class" archive="AppletTest.jar" width=320 height=320> 
  </applet> 
</body>
```

А можно сделать то же самое не в HTML, а в javascript?

Comment: Заработало с HTML. Это я координаты неправильно указала.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог - отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно внедрение апплета в HTML-документ выглядит как-то так.

```html
<applet code="MyApplet.class" archive="MyApplet.jar" width=120 height=120>
</applet>
```

- атрибут `code` указывает на имя класса, унаследованного от [`java.applet.Applet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html)
- атрибут `archive` содержит URL вашего JAR-файла, содержащего апплет.